# I can't fill in database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to make a database which I can fill from my webpage. I want it to be an Integer    input. I created a database and everything.
I connected php and phpmyadmin, but when I insert a number it adds an empty row (null).
Where did I go wrong?
This is the whole code...

This is the Insert.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SITE</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.html" method="post">     
Value1: <input type="text" name="field1-name" />
<input type="Submit" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is Connect.php

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="test";
$field1-name=$_POST['Value1'];
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES('$field1-name')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

And this is Test.php

```
<?php
include 'insert.html';
include 'connect.php';
$a=$_POST["temp"];
$sql="INSERT INTO temp(val) values ($a);";
?>
```

Comment: what kind of error you getting..

Comment: change this "INSERT INTO temp VALUES('$field1-name')" to "INSERT INTO temp VALUES($field1-name)". By using single quotes in -> '$field1-name' means it will treat it as string

Comment: Use `$_POST["field1-name"]` instead of `$_POST["Value1"]`. Also try to debug yourselves first using `var_dump($_POST);` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have it with your choice of variable names. You cannot have a dash in your variable name. So `$field1-name` is an invalid name. You should either remove the dash or change it to an underscore.

You also named your input `field1-name` but you try to access `$_POST['Value1']`. Where does `Value1` come from?

First fix your form so your input name does not have a dash:

```
<form action="insert.html" method="post">     
Value1: <input type="text" name="field1name" />
<input type="Submit" /></form>
```

Then fix your variable assignment:

```
$field1name=$_POST['field1name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your form action and form field name. on html file you can't get post values so change it to connect.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SITE</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Connect.php" method="post">     
Value1: <input type="text" name="field1_name" />
<input type="Submit" /></form>
</body>
</html>

This is Connect.php

<?php
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="test";
$field1_name=$_POST['field1_name'];
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES('$field1_name')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Connect.php you use:

```
$field1-name=$_POST['Value1'];
```

There are two problems with that. The variable name might be invalid and $_POST['Value1'] is always empty because the form field is named "field1-name".

Try this:

```
$value = $_POST['field1-name'];
...
$query = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES('$value')";
```

Comment: @RakeshShetty I'm not using $field1-name here. Are you commenting something else?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put connect.php in action and do whatever you want in connect.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SITE</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="connect.php" method="post">     
Value1: <input type="text" name="field1-name" />
<input type="Submit" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Connect.php

```
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="test";

$fieldname=$_POST['field1-name'];
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('".$fieldname."')";
mysql_query($query);
```